# I want to delete rows with a phrase but not additional text to the phrase in r

Tags: r, regex

I am currently using grep function and i have few rows that have the sentence "wet swab" and some rows with "wet swab from shirt" I want to delete rows which have only "wet swab" in it and not wet swab and additional text.

I have tried using

`data <- data[grep("\\bwet swab", data, invert = TRUE),]`

`data <- data[grep("\\bwet swab", data, invert = TRUE),]`

All rows that have the sentence wet swab, regardless if they have more text is getting deleted. I want to delete rows that only have the description wet swab deleted

Comment: `grepl("^wet swab$", c("wet swab", "wet swab and shirt"))`